Emgu.CV.Cuda problem: CudaInvoke.HasCuda always returns false even though I installed CUDA Toolkit
My GPU is RTX 1650 and I am using Windows 11. According to Geforce Experience, my drivers are up to date.
I installed Cuda Toolkit and added it to System Variables
proof that cuda is installed
The problem is Visual Studio doesn't recognize CUDA. CudaInvoke.HasCuda always returns false

My package versions are like that:
Emgu.CV 4.4.0.4099
Emgu.CV.runtime.windows.cuda 4.4.0.4099
I read this documentation: this one
I checked the versions but I can't see the problem.

https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

@PalleDue I am sorry, I am editing it even thought I fixed it

Nice, I revoked my downvote, welcome to StackOverflow.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Copy the x64 file in the Emgu.CV.runtime.windows.cuda package of nuget to the project directory

Fixed it a few minutes after posting that.
I had installed the same versions of Emgu.CV and Emgu.CV.runtime.windows.cuda. But I had to install the same version of Emgu.CV.runtime.windows, too.
It got fixed when I installed the same version of it too.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
